# unable to gain socket permissions in java

Tags: java, sockets

```
private boolean permissionsGranted() {
    final SocketPermission permission = new SocketPermission(
            "239.255.255.250", "connect,accept,resolve");
    try {
        AccessController.checkPermission(permission);
        return true;
    } catch (final AccessControlException e) {
        try {
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintStream("out2.txt"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

When running the above code in the Netbeans debug environment the above code returns `true`

but when complied to a .jar and run by simply double clicking the icon it will return `false` and I'm at a loss as to why.

I've tried self signing the jar but this did not help.

Comment: maybe your netbeans process is still running?

Comment: @RamonBoza, no it was closed at the time

Comment: If you're on Windows, try running it as admin.

Answer (score 1):

Verify if your machine has a firewall active, or jar permissions to executions in S.O.

Comment: the firewall on my win 8 machine is disabled at present

Comment: Verify in this block code if exception occurs, add 

ex.printStackTrace();


try {
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintStream("out2.txt"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
        }